# Pass selected value to Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a method named 'statement' in a balances controller (balances_controller.rb) that returns information from a specific date (@latestDate) to a view (statement.html.rb)

```
@latestDate = the most recent date in the 'date' column in the 'balances' table
```

In the view, I've also got a dropdown list of all the dates and when a date is selected, I'd like to be able to update the information so that in effect, the statement method is called again but the @latestDate is set to the selected value from the dropdown list.

How can I do this?

UPDATE:

I've modified my code with brito's suggestions. When I press the Search button, the form passes the following params:

```
?utf8=✓&date_id=30%2F12%2F2015&commit=Search
```

However, if I select a date and click Search, the @latestDate gets set and the h1 tag gets displayed correctly, but the rest of the data doesn't get returned.

CODE:

***balances_controller.rb***

```
  ....
  def statement
    @dates = Balance.select("distinct(date)").order('date desc')

    #Updated
    if (params[:date_id].blank?)
      @latestDate = Balance.order('date desc').first.date
    else
      @latestDate = params[:date_id]
    end

    @summaryBalances = Balance.joins(:account).order('accounts.credit').where('date = :abc', {abc: @latestDate})
  end
  ....
```

***balances/statement.html.rb***

```
....
<h1>Statement at <%= @latestDate %></h1>

#UPDATED
<%= form_tag("/statement", method: "get") do %>
<%= select_tag "date_id", options_for_select( @dates.collect {|d| [ d.date, d.date ] }) %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Balance</th>
      <th colspan="1"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @summaryBalances.each do |balance| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= balance.account.name %></td>    
        <td class='account-balance'><%= number_to_currency(balance.balance, unit: "£") %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_balance_path(balance) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
....
```

Answer (score 2):

A "dropdown" is a kind of input (HTML `<select>`). 
`<input>`s and `<select>`s must be within a `<form>` HTML element.

**Using pure HTML**

Whatever is in the `<form>` will be accessible in the `params` hash. So if you have a dropdown list, it should be within a `<form>` like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/yourroute" method="get">
  <select name="car">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

In the example above, the selected value (e.g. "volvo") will be available in the controller within `params["car"]`. Note that you would still have to define `/yourroute`.

**Using Rails' helper methods**

Of course, Rails helps you generate forms and inputs. You can use Rails' [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for that. For example, the following generates a search form ("Search" label, text box for input and a button) that sends a GET to the `/search` route:

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

To check and set @latestDate = balance[date_id] if the `balance[date_id]` was selected:

```
@latestDate ||= params[:balance[date_id]] unless params[:balance].blank?
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm attempting to use the helper method and clicking on the Search button, the querystring gets populated as such ... ?utf8=✓&balance[date_id]=13%2F10%2F2015&commit=Search. Is it possible to only pass the balance[date_id] value?

Comment: Rails generates some URL arguments such as `utf8=✓` automatically. I don't understand why would you need to remove them from the URL. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Just to tidy it up. In terms of checking if the argument exists and if so, reading it, ...    if (params[:balance[date_id]] != null)
      '@latestDate = params[:balance[date_id]] ... returns a NameError in BalancesController#statement.

Comment: Please update your code so that I can give further suggestions.

Comment: Have done. You'll see I've wrapped the dropdown control in a form helper.

Comment: @Bhav OK, I updated my answer with a line of code that will set `@latestDate` with balance[date_id] *only if* balance[date_id] exists, i.e., if the option was selected.

Comment: If I try to access the page (query string or no query string), I get ... undefined local variable or method `balance' for #<BalancesController:0x007fb628995be8>

Comment: @Bhav `balance` will try to call a function with that name. URL parameters are accessed through the `params` hash. Please look at the code added after **EDIT** in my answer.

Comment: Just seen your edit. ... undefined local variable or method `date_id' .... I think the issue is with :balance[date_id]. I don't receive any error if I replace it with :commit